# How to transfer data (Entities) from one database to another

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a system (using Entity Framework) that is deployed in various production systems and also on a quality control system. My problem is that data entry is often done only on one of those occurrences of my system (different databases).

I want to find the best way to transfer my data from one database to another database. Ids can change, as long as the relations between my objects are maintained. 98% of my data in in DB, some of it is external files, I can manage those separately, manually.

Currently we use a xml structure as a transition file. The file is then imported in the destination system, and code manually imports the entities and re-creates the data.

I'm looking for a more generic way to do this, with less code. Since all my data in stored in Entities couldn't I simply create a big List and throw all my objects in there, then serialize that in some matter into an external file and finally generically import all the entities in there in my destination system? (I'll probably have to be careful in maintaining relation ids, but should be ok...)

Anyways I'm wondering if anyone would have smart approaches, I'm pretty sure I,m not the first with a similar problem.

Thanks!

Comment: And you want to EF over SSIS because....

Comment: Because I don't know about SSIS ? I'll look into it today, drop links if you can.

Comment: #Sébastien sorry about that I added an answer, good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get some process around this. If all environments contain the same data (unlikely) you can replicate. It is the most automatic. But a QA environ should not update production, so you have to really think this through.

If semi-automated is okay, there are tools out there you can use from a variety of vendors. I use Red Gate tools, personally, but others are also fine.

Can you set up a more automated push with EF? Sure, but the amount of time you spend is really not worth it.

Comment: The reason is pretty specific and common here, we have this demo coming up, so we need to produce demo content for that demo. We want to produce that on our QC environnement, then once that's stable (will bring bugs to light for sure), release that on a "demo" "dummy" prod site so it's accessible from the web. Red Gate seams a good solution, but it's a tad expensive.

Comment: If you just have to get through THIS demo, the tool manufacturers all have a trial period. I think Red Gate is 14, Altova is 30. I have not tried Devart, but they are a bit less expensive. With a bit of programming, Sync Framework might work, but since I have not played with it yet, I don't want to get into recommending that path.

Comment: And how about a "code" approach instead of a database approach, any solution in there? Like serializing the ORM and such ?

Comment: You can do that, but you have to plan this much better than "they can have different IDs". Any of the Microsoft disconnected data paradigms allow you to set up a context in another database. EF is a bit of a pain compared to datasets, but it is not impossible. I might also examine Sync Framework for a code approach, but I have no expertise, so I am not outright recommending.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you can check some of the following approaches:

1) Use Sql Compare or Sql Data Compare. Those tools are from [Red Gate](http://www.red-gate.com/) and can be found [here](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/)

2) Regular backups and restores of the databases. You could, if it is an option regularly backup your most up-to-date database and restore it on the destination systems. I have no experience in automatizing this but here is a [link](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article489-backup-and-restore-database-in-aspnet-.aspx) to do that through .net.

3) You could always give it a go creating a version control system of your own. I would picture one such system selecting all records from a certain table (or all of them), deleting all records in the target database and inserting them. This seems pretty complex though, as you have to worry about relationships, data dependencies, etc.

Hope this helps in some way.
Regards

---

Answer (score 1):

If you for some reason will not be satisfied with existing tools may be you'll want take a look at the [Sync Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb887608) and implement this functionality yourself for your very particular data bases.

Answer (score 1):

Given what you described, pushing data from One SQL Server to another for demo purposes, you should consider [SQL Server Integration Services](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/integration.aspx).

If you're got a simple scenario where you just move the data and objects from DB to the next you can use their built-in Wizards. If you need to do custom stuff you can build complex workflows using C# and SQL (tools you already know). Note: most of what you're going to want comes with the [standard edition](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/editions-compare.aspx) so if you're using express this is less interesting.

The story for Red Gate products is more compelling when you don't have SQL Server (So you have to go out and buy something) and if you are interested in finding out what the changes are between DB's (like viewing code changes in a .cs file in a source control product)

Comment: The challenge is not only to move data from one database to another, but to move the specific SLICE of data that is indirectly connected to a certain ID in the database.

Comment: @NielsBrinch I thought I addressed that with *if you need to do custom stuff you can build complex workflows using C# and SQL*

Comment: Sorry, I put that comment on the wrong post. My mistake. Sorry for the confusion.